# Site being scaled down by unknown forces

Tags: responsive

For some reason, my site has suddenly started scaling down strangely and I have no idea of the cause:
[image]

The font-sizes, widths of elements, all point to the site having way larger width that it actually has... e.g. the font-size in that image is apparently 16px. I imagine I'd need to post the code for you guys to help find the exact cause, but it's a hell of a lot so I was just curious if anyone's seen this sort of thing before and might have some idea.

I'll keep hunting.

**Edit:** It's not doing this in Firefox and is responding correctly, just Chrome having the issue, but Chrome and Firefox on Android is the same for me

Also worth noting that the issue isn't happening when I resize the browser, only when I use device preview or view it on an actual mobile device.

Putting `$(window).width()` in the console gives "980px" whenever the device is below 980px wide, but reports correctly above it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it...

Needed to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Annoying because I had this in my initial frontend markup but when building it into a Wordpress theme I thought WP would take care of it, guess not